# Docker stack won't populate a named volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a named-volume container deploying shared resources to worker nodes in a swarm for a production release.  It seems to deploy, but won't populate the named volume.

The image for this container looks like this:

```
FROM alpine
RUN mkdir $HOME/node_modules
COPY ./node_modules $HOME/node_modules
VOLUME $HOME/node_modules
```

When built, the image copies the current set of modules from the dev machine into a layer in the container.  This container is then deployed on a worker node as a service, defined in the compose  file as:

```
      version: "3"
      services:
        nmod_core:
          image: nmod_core:1.0.0
          environment:
            - HOME=/root
          volumes:
            - nmod_core:$HOME/node_modules
          deploy:
            replicas: 2
            placement:
              constraints: [node.role == worker] 
            restart_policy:
              condition: on-failure
              max_attempts: 1
```

On deployment, docker creates a named volume on each worker node according to this script.  Creating a named volume means it creates a host directory at /var/lib/docker/volumes/nmod_core/_data and copies the container's node_modules contents into that directory.

The container exits since it has no ongoing process.  So I set a restart limit of 1 so the service will not keep trying to restart it.  The data persists in the host directory because it's a named volume--that's the objective--other containers on the same node should be able to mount it.

With credentials to my private registry set up, I deploy the stack via:

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml myapp --with-registry-auth
```

I watch the service get created. When I log into the worker nodes ***docker image ls*** shows the correct image has been pulled from the registry.  Presumably these containers have indeed run because ***docker volume ls*** shows the named volume has been created on each node, called myapp_nmod_core.  I can ***inspect*** these volumes and they report the mount location as /var/lib/docker/volumes/myapp_nmod_core/_data.  However, this location does not exist on the node.

Nevertheless, I can mount this named volume to a container via:

```
docker run -v myapp_nmod_core:/nmod -it alpine
#/ ls /nmod
#/
```

However, as shown above, the volume is empty.

But if I run the container manually on the node:

```
docker run -it f2f55823173d
#/ ls /root/node_modules
   [a big list of node modules]
```

I get different results:   ***docker volume ls*** shows a new volume created.  Inspect shows a similar mount path, which also doesn't exist.  However, when I mount that named volume in a secondary container as above, I get the volume mounted to the specified mount point and it now contains the big list of node modules I'm looking for.

So when deployed via docker swarm, I get the image and the volume, and I can mount it in another container, but the contents of the volume are missing.  When I run the same image manually, the contents of the volume are all correct.

Any clues/insight greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: This is not an answer therefore I write a comment. Maybe you should run the Docker daemon in debug mode -> https://success.docker.com/KBase/How_do_I_enable_%22debug%22_logging_of_the_Docker_daemon%3F, because maybe you caught a bug and therefore the debug mode will provide more details.

Comment: also this is not an answer, but have you checked to see if the service that requires the data in the volume is running on a different node?

Comment: To be fair the documentation for `VOLUME` only talks about how `docker run` will populate any newly created volume, not `docker stack deploy`. See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume